# How do I get parameter names for both getter and setter of the same COM object property?

Tags: c#, .net, com, typelib

I need to parse a type library and analyze parameters of each method of each interface. So I get to an interface, obtain `ITypeInfo` and `TYPEATTR` for that interface, then enumerate all methods and for each one call `ITypeInfo::GetFuncDesc()` and obtain `FUNCDESC` and use its `memid` member when calling `ITypeInfo.GetNames()`.

The problem is that for each property that has both a getter and a setter both have the same `memid` and so when I call `GetNames()` it returns parameters of a getter but I can't even ask it to obtain data for the setter because there's no parameter to specify that I want "another one with the same memid".

How do I obtain parameter names for both getter and setter of the same property (and so having the same memid)?

Comment: Hmm, no, a memid is not a dispid.